# Empty select result when dates are used

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, resultset

*Initial data:* have a paragraph of query which in the sake of reasoning can be simplified to next

```
SELECT MAX((CASE 
          WHEN to_char(sysdate, 'DY') = 'SAT' THEN 1 
          WHEN to_char(sysdate, 'DY') = 'SUN' THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END)) status 
FROM mytable WHERE mycondition;
```

*The problem:* it appears that if mycondition results in empty result set first two when conditions don't work as they should and return null instead of 1. If I simply substitute the last line of query with next

```
FROM dual;
```

first two when conditions work flawless.

*Condition:* It should only be a query, no ifs, var defs etc.

How is it possible to perform this type of select but without a null value returned?

**P.S.:** Can use NVL/NVL2 but that really complicates the thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query doesn't return any fields from the mytable. Why is it included at all?

Comment: @Olaf, I wrote there if, which means it does in some cases.

Comment: your reproduction was probably not the same as original version is, as it failed in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a NVL function:

```
SELECT NVL(MAX((CASE 
          WHEN to_char(sysdate, 'DY') = 'SAT' THEN 1 
          WHEN to_char(sysdate, 'DY') = 'SUN' THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END)), 1) status 
FROM mytable WHERE mycondition;
```

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN works fine, your problem is with MAX.

MAX and MIN return null when no rows match while SUM and COUNT return 0.

I'm afraid den-javamaniac is right, you need NVL, or perhaps a smart use of DECODE if you cannot switch out MAX.